# Using Recursion in Mips

Tags: mips

I want to do a program by using recursion. I am going to use if-else. The question is:
Do I have to return something in each case of if-else?

Comment: Perhaps you could outline your proposed recursive function using e.g. C or even just pseudo code ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a stack trace for each transfer of pointer to a new location. And in order to implement recursion, you need to return something in each case of if-else, or at least after each if-else you need to perform some operation and store the result in a memory location which is global and accessible anywhere from your code.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion in assembler is not all that different from a loop.

When doing recursion in assembler, make sure you're not demolishing the variables you had in your registers!